# What is the type of moss that commonly grows in dirt, trees, and bricks?

Tags: identification, houseplants, moss

I'm trying to grow moss for my paludarium, and there's a certain type of moss that is very common (especially during fall) that you can see growing in hard-packed dirt, trees, and bricks -- (at least where I'm from, Houston, TX, US). It is very common, and looks like:

[image]

Is there a certain name for this? I don't think it's java moss or sphagnum, it looks quite different and doesn't get as big. I've tried everywhere and it appears that this is just "moss", but is there at least some type of scientific classification?

## Edit

After doing some research, I found two possible classifications: [*Bryophyta oedipodium*](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1366&bih=667&q=oedipodiopsida&oq=oedipodiopsida&gs_l=img.3..0i5i10j0i10i24.5238.5503.0.5834.2.2.0.0.0.0.142.259.0j2.2.0....0...1ac.1.30.img..0.2.258.R11yZtuMctk) and [*Bryophyta bryopsida*](https://www.google.com/search?q=bryopsida&espv=210&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=DPN3Utf4NaTi2gXHg4CoCg&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=667) (true moss). Is it either of these? I am by no means an expert on plant life, I'm doing this for my amphibians, so if anyone is familiar with mosses, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: with over 12,000 species this is a tough question. have you looked at acrocarpus mosses?

Comment: @kevinsky Yeah, I didn't realize how hard it is until _after_ I asked this question. :P The first two pictures if you look up "acrocarpus mosses" in Google images looks like it _could_ be what I'm looking for, though I'm not sure, and I certainly don't want to misidentify them. If you google "true moss" that's exactly what I'm looking for, except there's no official classification or a Wikipedia page on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be Cushion Moss (Leucobryum)?

Sorry, not trying to advertise for them, but the Moss Acres picture seems very similar.

http://www.mossacres.com/product_cushion_moss.asp